# Google spreadsheet color sheet tab

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google script in a spreadsheet and I would like to color the sheet tab. Do you have any idea how to do ?

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the setbackground's function

I show you an example :

```
Function colorRow(r){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var c = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, c);

    dataRange.setBackground("white");

}
```

Doc : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTabColor().

From the Google documentation you use it like this:

```
// This example assumes there is a sheet named "first"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
first.setTabColor("ff0000"); // Set the color to red.
first.setTabColor(null); // Unset the color.
```